# Netflix forced language localisation

Tags: localization, netflix, subtitles

A friend of mine who went on an exchange to Denmark asked me for help, because sometimes he just wants to see movies in Spanish, or at least with the subtitles in Spanish. But he said that every movie he sees has the subtitles in Danish and he cannot change the language.

Is there any way to ask Netflix to change the language, or at least to trick it to believe he is in a Spanish speaking country?

As you know, using proxies would be unacceptably slow.

Is there a video-ready *hide-my-ip* software out there?

Is there any other faster way to do this?

Comment: "As you know, proxies would be unacceptably slow.". I disagree, paid proxies are often fast. E.g. you can try http://hidemyass.com/vpn/.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Paying an extra proxy just for subtitles would be a solution, but I don't think that it would be practical(If you just use it for that). Thanks anyway for the advice. Any other idea?

Comment: Not really: the two main solutions to mask your IP are 1) website exploits (unlikely for Netflix) 2) proxies. Unless you find a free proxy with decent speed (good luck), you're screwed (remember if you have a good connection you can put a server in your place and use it as a proxy). Also, it might be worth investigating whether the issue is the IP (I don't know how Netflix handles language localisation).

Comment: (btw in case you wonder, I didnt't downvote your question)

Comment: (I have no idea how Netfix’s works, but) How about changing his computer’s/browser’s main language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has he tried VPN like hide my ass: http://vpnverge.com/truths-about-hidemyass/ or DNS service like smartyDNS?

Comment: SmartyDNS seems wonderful!(apoarently, it would allow setting netflix to at least english) It is cheaper and has a good trial period. If this works, I think that it is worthy.

Comment: I use ExpressVPN and it works great.  It also has a multi-user licence so I use it on my mobile and PC as well as the Amazon Firestick.